# How i can do redirect from loop?

Tags: ruby

We have an array and need to check its elements. If the elements have a common feature, the loop continues, else the loop is aborted. How can I send redirect if the loop will be aborted?

Example code:

```
array = [1, 1, 3, 2, 2]
i = 0
while i < array.count - 1
  if *check common feature*
    *some code*
  else
    value = 'error'
  end
  break if (value = 'error')
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*send redirect*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `else` just

```
redirect_to whatever_path
```

Comment: Ooh, apparently I'm tangled in different ways, but it seemed to me that writes a mistake. So now everything is working. Thank.